# Loading XDocument in memory

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

This is probably a really simple question, but I'm kind of learning as I go along! So some of the programming might seem a little amateur!

I'm developing an application that uses the WizardPages control to create a wizard-like interface where the tabs are hidden. There are 5 "steps" to the wizard, each with its own tab.

In step 3 of the wizard, an XML document is loaded based on user selection. They can choose to load the default XML or provide a path to a custom XML file. A loadXML() method is called at a button click event on step 3, with an if statement saying "if default option is selected, load from default path, else load from path the user specified". This loading of the XML then populates a list box in step 4. I'm using XML to LINQ, as you can see from the snippet below.

```
    private void loadXML()
    {
        if (configFilePathTextBox.Enabled == true)
        {
            // Load XML from that path
            XDocument config = XDocument.Load(configFilePathTextBox.Text);
            // Populate next screen
            IEnumerable<XElement> elList =
                from el in config.Descendants("software_entry")
                select el;
            foreach (XElement el in elList)
                listBox1.Items.Add(el.Attribute("name"));
            MessageBox.Show("Configuration file loaded successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            // Load XML from default path
            XDocument config = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\config.xml");
            // Populate next screen
            IEnumerable<XElement> elList =
                from el in config.Descendants("software_entry")
                select el;
            foreach (XElement el in elList)
                listBox1.Items.Add(el.Attribute("name"));
            MessageBox.Show("Configuration file loaded successfully.");
        }
    }
```

This works, but is there a way to load the XDocument so that it can be accessed in all methods? As it is, I have to use the XDocument.Load method each time I want to do anything with it, and at each loading I have to use the same if statement to determine which file to load (the default or the custom).

This gets really confusing as in step 5 of my application, I am trying to create a foreach loop to iterate through each entry in a listbox from step 4 (which is populated by this XML document), retrieve additional attribute information based on the one in the listbox (which is just the name of software, other attributes include file type, path etc.) and then write a line to a batch file with all of this information. As it is, I have no idea how to properly format this loop taking into consideration the if loop for the XDocument loading.

I thought about using the second method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123724/linq-to-xml-keep-xdocument-loaded), but I'm not sure how to incorporate the user selection element from my 3rd step in that. I'm just a little confused!

Thanks for any help. I'm not great at explaining the problem, so ask questions if you need any more information/clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare it in a [public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) scope. For example a [public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of a class that other methods have access to. It seems like you don't care about this though as you only want to use the program.cs file.

To use it as a field, your code could become:

```
public class Program
{
    XDocument document;

    private void loadXML()
    {            
        if (configFilePathTextBox.Enabled == true)
        {
            document = XDocument.Load(configFilePathTextBox.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            document = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\config.xml");
        }

        IEnumerable<XElement> elList =
            from el in document.Descendants("software_entry")
            select el;

        foreach (XElement el in elList)
            listBox1.Items.Add(el.Attribute("name"));

        MessageBox.Show("Configuration file loaded successfully.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and all of my code thus far has been done by viewing the code for certain forms I've designed. I have no added classes - the only one I have is the default Program.cs.

Comment: It could be a field of Program, but typically you don't want too much code in Program.cs

Comment: Brilliant, that works perfectly. Thank you very much!

I have difficulty getting my head around the structure of a C# application when I use VS2010 and forms, as it's different to most of the thorough online documentation/guides, but it was the way I was taught.

Comment: @CSF90 You might consider checking out this [C# tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx), specifically Lessons on Classes.